# Проконсультируйте новичка

Tags: javascript

Возник такой вот вопрос. Работаю с продажей недвижимости и постоянно работаю с досками объявлений. На каждой доске всегда есть формы при добавлении нового объявления, а так как работаю с большим количеством объявлений, занимает много времени вручную заполнять все. Суть такова, возможно кто-то даст интересные ссылки либо поможет написать небольшой скрипт для автозаполнения форм. Через инспектора вырезал форму. Буду очень благодарен за любую полезную информацию.

```js
<form method="POST" id="object_form" enctype="multipart/form-data" style="margin: 0 auto">

  
  <script type="text/javascript">
    var objectFormDynamicAllFields = ['room_count', 'square_total', 'square_land', 'floor'];
  var objectFormDynamicTypeFields = {};
              objectFormDynamicTypeFields['1'] = ['room_count', 'square_total', 'floor'];
          objectFormDynamicTypeFields['2'] = ['square_total', 'floor'];
          objectFormDynamicTypeFields['3'] = ['room_count', 'square_total', 'floor'];
          objectFormDynamicTypeFields['4'] = ['room_count', 'square_total', 'floor'];
          objectFormDynamicTypeFields['5'] = ['room_count', 'square_total', 'square_land', 'floor'];
          objectFormDynamicTypeFields['6'] = ['room_count', 'square_total', 'square_land', 'floor'];
          objectFormDynamicTypeFields['7'] = ['room_count', 'square_total', 'square_land', 'floor'];
          objectFormDynamicTypeFields['8'] = ['room_count', 'square_total', 'square_land', 'floor'];
          objectFormDynamicTypeFields['9'] = ['square_land'];
          objectFormDynamicTypeFields['10'] = ['room_count', 'square_total', 'floor'];
          objectFormDynamicTypeFields['11'] = [];
          objectFormDynamicTypeFields['12'] = ['square_total', 'square_land'];
          objectFormDynamicTypeFields['13'] = ['square_total'];
          objectFormDynamicTypeFields['14'] = ['square_total'];
          objectFormDynamicTypeFields['15'] = ['square_total'];
          objectFormDynamicTypeFields['16'] = ['square_total'];
          objectFormDynamicTypeFields['17'] = ['square_total'];
          objectFormDynamicTypeFields['18'] = ['square_total'];
          objectFormDynamicTypeFields['19'] = ['square_total', 'square_land'];
          objectFormDynamicTypeFields['20'] = ['square_total', 'square_land', 'floor'];
          objectFormDynamicTypeFields['21'] = [];
          objectFormDynamicTypeFields['22'] = ['square_total'];
  </script>
  <input id="object_district_id_val" name="object[district_id]" value="" type="hidden">  <input id="object_city_id" name="object[city_id]" value="" type="hidden">
  <table class="ClassicForm" cellspacing="0">
          
<tbody><tr id="object_form_row_deal_type_id">
  <th class="">
    <nobr><label for="object_deal_type_id"><span>Тип объявления</span><span class="RequiredStar">*</span></label></nobr>
  </th>
  <td>
  <select name="object[deal_type_id]" class="InputMedium" id="object_deal_type_id">
<option value="1" selected="selected">Продам</option>
<option value="2">Куплю</option>
<option value="3">Сдам в аренду</option>
<option value="6">Сдам в аренду посуточно</option>
<option value="4">Сниму в аренду</option>
<option value="5">Обменяю</option>
</select>
     </td>
</tr>          
<tr id="object_form_row_object_type_id">
  <th class="">
    <nobr><label for="object_object_type_id"><span>Тип объекта</span><span class="RequiredStar">*</span></label></nobr>
  </th>
  <td>
  <select name="object[object_type_id]" class="InputMedium" id="object_object_type_id">
<option value="1" selected="selected">Квартира</option>
<option value="2">Комната</option>
<option value="3">Гостинка</option>
<option value="4">Квартира в новостройке</option>
<option value="Квартира в новостройкеa-sep-" disabled="disabled">--------------------------------</option>
<option value="5">Коттедж</option>
<option value="6">Дом</option>
<option value="7">Таунхаус</option>
<option value="8">Дача</option>
<option value="Дачаa-sep-" disabled="disabled">--------------------------------</option>
<option value="9">Земельный участок</option>
<option value="Земельный участокa-sep-" disabled="disabled">--------------------------------</option>
<option value="10">Офис</option>
<option value="11">Бизнес</option>
<option value="12">Имущественный комплекс</option>
<option value="13">Гараж, стоянка, паркоместо</option>
<option value="14">Торговая недвижимость</option>
<option value="15">Склад</option>
<option value="16">Производственное помещение</option>
<option value="17">Кафе, бар, ресторан</option>
<option value="18">Магазин, киоск, МАФ</option>
<option value="19">СТО</option>
<option value="20">Административное здание</option>
<option value="Административное зданиеa-sep-" disabled="disabled">--------------------------------</option>
<option value="21">Другой объект</option>
<option value="22">Помещения свободного назначения</option>
</select>
     </td>
</tr>          
<tr id="object_form_row_room_count">
  <th class="">
    <nobr><label for="object_room_count"><span class="TipsyTooltip" original-title="Для большей отдачи от объявления, не забудьте указать количество комнат в заголовке сообщения.">Количество комнат</span><span class="RequiredStar">*</span></label></nobr>
  </th>
  
  <input name="object[room_count]" value="4" class="InputMedium valid" id="object_room_count" type="text">
     
</tr>    
    
<tr id="object_form_row_square_total">
  <th class="">
    <nobr><label for="object_square_total"><span>Площадь (м кв.)</span></label></nobr>
  </th>
  <td>
  <input name="object[square_total]" value="132.00" class="InputShort" placeholder="общая" id="object_square_total" type="text"><span class="Separator">/</span><input name="object[square_live]" value="321.00" class="InputShort" placeholder="жилая" id="object_square_live" type="text"><span class="Separator">/</span><input name="object[square_kitchen]" value="321.00" class="InputShort" placeholder="кухня" id="object_square_kitchen" type="text">
     </td>
</tr>
    
<tr id="object_form_row_square_land" style="display: none;">
  <th class="">
    <nobr><label for="object_square_land"><span>Площадь участка (соток)</span></label></nobr>
  </th>
  <td>
  <input name="object[square_land]" class="InputMedium" id="object_square_land" type="text">
     </td>
</tr>
    
<tr id="object_form_row_floor">
  <th class="">
    <nobr><label for="object_floor"><span>Этаж</span></label></nobr>
  </th>
  <td>
  <input name="object[floor]" value="11" class="InputShort" placeholder="этаж" id="object_floor" type="text"><span class="Separator">/</span><input name="object[floors]" value="23" class="InputShort" placeholder="всего" id="object_floors" type="text">
     </td>
</tr>
          
<tr id="object_form_row_region_id">
  <th class="">
    <nobr><label for="object_region_id"><span>Регион</span><span class="RequiredStar">*</span></label></nobr>
  </th>
  <td>
  <select name="object[region_id]" class="InputMedium" id="object_region_id">
<option value="1" selected="selected">г. Киев</option>
<option value="2">Киевская область</option>
<option value="Киевская областьa-sep-" disabled="disabled">--------------------------------</option>
<option value="3">АР Крым</option>
<option value="4">Винницкая область</option>
<option value="5">Волынская область</option>
<option value="6">Днепропетровская область</option>
<option value="7">Донецкая область</option>
<option value="8">Житомирская область</option>
<option value="9">Закарпатская область</option>
<option value="10">Запорожская область</option>
<option value="11">Ивано-Франковская область</option>
<option value="12">Кировоградская область</option>
<option value="13">Луганская область</option>
<option value="14">Львовская область</option>
<option value="15">Николаевская область</option>
<option value="16">Одесская область</option>
<option value="17">Полтавская область</option>
<option value="18">Ровенская область</option>
<option value="19">Сумская область</option>
<option value="20">Тернопольская область</option>
<option value="21">Харьковская область</option>
<option value="22">Херсонская область</option>
<option value="23">Хмельницкая область</option>
<option value="24">Черкасская область</option>
<option value="25">Черниговская область</option>
<option value="26">Черновицкая область</option>
<option value="Черновицкая областьa-sep-" disabled="disabled">--------------------------------</option>
<option value="27">Кипр</option>
<option value="28">Россия</option>
<option value="29">Другая страна</option>
</select>
     </td>
</tr>          
<tr id="object_form_row_district_id" style="display: table-row;">
  <th class="">
    <nobr><label for="object_district_id"><span>Район</span></label></nobr>
  </th>
  <td>
  <select name="object[district_id]" class="InputMedium" id="object_district_id"><option value="-1">- Выберите район -</option><option value="1">Голосеевский</option><option value="2">Дарницкий</option><option value="3">Деснянский</option><option value="4">Днепровский</option><option value="5">Оболонский</option><option value="6">Печерский</option><option value="7">Подольский</option><option value="8">Святошинский</option><option value="9">Соломенский</option><option value="10">Шевченковский</option></select><input id="object_district_id_val" value="2" type="hidden">
     </td>
</tr>          
<tr id="object_form_row_address_city" style="display: none;">
  <th class="">
    <nobr><label for="object_address_city"><span>Населенный пункт</span><span class="RequiredStar">*</span></label></nobr>
  </th>
  <td>
  <input name="object[address_city]" value="" class="InputMedium placeholder ui-autocomplete-input" placeholder="введите первые буквы названия" id="object_address_city" autocomplete="off" role="textbox" aria-autocomplete="list" aria-haspopup="true" type="text"><input id="object_address_city_val" value="" type="hidden">
     </td>
</tr>          
<tr id="object_form_row_city_district_id">
  <th class="">
    <nobr><label for="object_city_district_id"><span>form_city_district_id</span></label></nobr>
  </th>
  <td>
  <select name="object[city_district_id]" class="InputMedium" id="object_city_district_id">
<option value="" selected="selected"></option>
</select>
     </td>
</tr>    
    
<tr id="object_form_row_address_street">
  <th class="">
    <nobr><label for="object_address_street"><span>Адрес</span></label></nobr>
  </th>
  <td>
  <input name="object[address_street]" value="вфівіфв" class="InputShort" placeholder="улица" id="object_address_street" type="text"> <input name="object[address_house_number]" value="11" class="InputShort" placeholder="№ дома" id="object_address_house_number" type="text">
     </td>
</tr>
          
<tr id="object_form_row_title">
  <th class="">
    <nobr><label for="object_ru_title"><span class="TipsyTooltip" original-title="<strong>Заголовок объявления</strong> должен быть максимально информативным, в нем необходимо указать операцию с недвижимостью, тип недвижимости, район недвижимости.<br/><br/>Не стоит указывать цену в заголовке — это может сразу отбить интерес у потенциального покупателя. Узнав цену, он может перейти к изучению других объектов, не увидев преимуществ, отображенных в описании.<br/><br/><b>Примеры хороших заголовков:</b><br/>Продам 3к квартиру, Позняки<br/>Сдам офис, 180 м.кв., 1 этаж, Оболонские липки">Заголовок объявления</span><span class="RequiredStar">*</span></label></nobr>
  </th>
  <td>
  <input maxlength="70" name="object[ru][title]" value="Віфвіфвфівіфвфівфівіввфівфівфівіфвіф" class="InputMedium" id="object_ru_title" type="text">&nbsp;<span class="GrayText HelpCursor" id="object_ru_title_chars_remain" title="Осталось символов">(34)</span>
     </td>
</tr>          
<tr id="object_form_row_description">
  <th class="">
    <nobr><label for="object_ru_description"><span class="TipsyTooltip" original-title="Текст хорошего объявления должен содержать расширенную информацию об объекте: метраж, состояние объекта, транспортная инфраструктура, наличие магазинов, школ, и т.д.">Текст объявления</span><span class="RequiredStar">*</span></label></nobr>
  </th>
  <td>
  <textarea rows="4" cols="30" maxlength="1000" name="object[ru][description]" class="InputMedium" id="object_ru_description">віфвіфвіфвіфвіфвіфвіфвфі</textarea>&nbsp;<span class="GrayText HelpCursor" id="object_ru_description_chars_remain" title="Осталось символов">(976)</span>
     </td>
</tr>    
    
<tr id="object_form_row_price">
  <th class="">
    <nobr><label for="object_price"><span>Цена</span><span class="RequiredStar">*</span></label></nobr>
  </th>
  <td>
  <input name="object[price]" value="1111111.00" class="InputShort" id="object_price" type="text"> <select name="object[currency_id]" class="InputShort" id="object_currency_id">
<option value="1">$</option>
<option value="2" selected="selected">грн.</option>
<option value="3">€</option>
</select> <select name="object[price_type_id]" class="InputShort" id="object_price_type_id">
<option value="1" selected="selected">за объект</option>
<option value="2">за м кв.</option>
<option value="3">за сотку</option>
<option value="4">в сутки</option>
<option value="5">в месяц</option>
</select>
     </td>
</tr>    
<tr id="object_form_row_contact_owner_type_id">
  <th class="">
    <nobr><label for="object_contact_owner_type_id"><span>Кем вы являетесь?</span><span class="RequiredStar">*</span></label></nobr>
  </th>
  <td>
  <ul class="radio_list"><li><input name="object[contact_owner_type_id]" value="1" id="object_contact_owner_type_id_1" class="InputMedium" type="radio">&nbsp;<label for="object_contact_owner_type_id_1">Профессионал</label></li>
<li><input name="object[contact_owner_type_id]" value="2" id="object_contact_owner_type_id_2" class="InputMedium" type="radio">&nbsp;<label for="object_contact_owner_type_id_2">Представитель хозяина (без комиссии)</label></li>
<li><input name="object[contact_owner_type_id]" value="3" id="object_contact_owner_type_id_3" checked="checked" class="InputMedium" type="radio">&nbsp;<label for="object_contact_owner_type_id_3">Хозяин</label></li></ul>
     </td>
</tr>
    <tr id="object_form_row_contact_name">
  <th>
    <nobr><label for="object_contact_name">Ваше имя<span class="RequiredStar">*</span></label></nobr>
  </th>
  <td>
          Юрий <a target="_blank" class="Extern" href="/user/profile/edit/">изменить</a>    
  </td>
</tr>    <tr id="object_form_row_contact_phones">
  <th class="">
    <nobr><label for="contact_phone_first">Контактные телефоны<span class="RequiredStar">*</span></label></nobr>
  </th>
  <td>
                  <div class="ContactPhoneContainer">(044) 213-21-32</div>
          
    
  </td>
</tr>
    
<tr id="object_form_row_main_image_id">
  <th class="">
    <nobr><label for="object_main_image_id"><span class="TipsyTooltip" title="Загрузка большого количества фотографий может занять несколько минут.<br/>Пожалуйста, дождитесь окончания загрузки.">Фотографии объекта</span></label></nobr>
  </th>
  <td>
  <table id="object_images_sortable" class="ClassicForm" cellspacing="3">
 
      <tbody class="ui-sortable"><tr id="new_image_1">
      <td class="Light3" style="padding: 5px">
        Изображение #1<br>
        <input name="object_images[1]" id="object_images[1]" type="file">&nbsp;<img style="cursor: pointer" src="/magicLibsPlugin/images/delete.png" onclick="remove_image('new_image_1'); return false;" title="Удалить изображение">
      </td>
    </tr>  
    
    <!--
  <tr>
    <td colspan="2" class="warning">image_not_uploaded</td>
  </tr>
  -->
  </tbody></table>

<table id="infosoft_grid" class="ClassicForm" style="width: 100%" cellspacing="3">
    <tbody><tr>
    <th class="Light3" style="text-align: center; padding: 3px 0 5px 0">
      <ul class="GridFormActions">
        <li class="GridActionAdd">
          <span class="Link" onclick="add_object_image('object_images_sortable');">Добавить изображение</span>
          <input value="0" id="object_images_count" type="hidden">
        </li>
      </ul>
    </th>
  </tr>
</tbody></table>

<input name="idh" value="1658913" type="hidden">
<div id="image_order_data"></div>
     </td>
</tr>    
        

    
            <tr>
      <td colspan="2" style="text-align: center;">
              Соберите картинку:
                      <div style="padding-left: 70px;">
                                <input name="capcode" id="capcode" value="1|2|3|4|5" type="hidden">
                                          <!-- KeyCAPTCHA code (www.keycaptcha.com) --><script type="text/javascript">var s_s_c_user_id = '112478';var s_s_c_session_id = '590f2e2d339ad-4.0.0.001';var s_s_c_captcha_field_id = 'capcode';var s_s_c_submit_button_id = 'postbut';var s_s_c_web_server_sign = 'ea168e69002393782094aca175f6157d';var s_s_c_web_server_sign2 = 'f94a08a3729cc412fbf05766950bf4e1';</script><script language="JavaScript" src="http://backs.keycaptcha.com/swfs/cap.js"></script><div id="div_for_keycaptcha" style="border: medium none; background: transparent none repeat scroll 0% 0%; padding: 0px; margin: 0px; height: 223px;"><iframe style="width:0;height:0;border:none;" src="https://back10.keycaptcha.com/swfs/session.html?r=0.22601948443446884"></iframe><script id="s_s_c_caps_scr" src="https://back10.keycaptcha.com/swfs/caps.js?uid=112478&amp;u=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.prostodom.ua%2Fcatalog%2F1658913%2Fedit%2F%3Freturn%3Dhttp%253A%252F%252Fwww.prostodom.ua%252Fcatalog%252Fmy_objects%252F&amp;r=0.5629558568498065" type="text/javascript"></script><div id="s_s_c_flashcap" style="border:0px; padding:0; margin:0; display:none;"></div><div id="ca446f3a168ed614da08c48dfc8" style="width: 474px; height: 180px; border: 0px none; padding: 0px; margin: 0px; position: relative;"><div id="s_s_c_border" style="z-index: 96; position: absolute; background: transparent none repeat scroll 0% 0%; line-height: normal; padding: 0px; margin: 0px; width: 474px; height: 223px; top: 0px; left: 0px; border: 1px solid rgb(0, 0, 0); opacity: 1;"><div id="s_s_c_back" style="width: 100%; height: 100%; padding: 0px; margin: 0px; background: transparent none repeat scroll 0% 0%; position: absolute; top: 0px; left: 0px; opacity: 0;"></div><div id="s_s_c_back2" style="position: absolute; left: 0px; top: 0px; width: 472px; height: 178px; z-index: 95; margin: 0px; padding: 0px; background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);"></div><canvas id="ATBwgFTHoXTUT" style="position: absolute; left: 0px; top: 0px; z-index: 97;" width="472" height="160"></canvas><div id="s_s_c_desc" style="position: absolute; left: 0px; top: 0px; width: 100%; height: 100%; color: rgb(85, 85, 85); margin: 0px; padding: 0px; background: transparent none repeat scroll 0% 0%; opacity: 1; text-align: center; z-index: 999;"><div id="s_s_c_backdesc" style="background-color:#FFFFFF;padding:0;margin:0;position:absolute;left:0;right:0;width:100%;height:178px;opacity:0.8;">&nbsp;</div><div style="font-size:18px; z-index:1000; position:absolute; margin:0; padding:0; width:100%; top:61px; font-family:serif; font-weight:normal; text-align:center;">Соберите картинку, как в правом верхнем углу</div><div id="kc_sample_image_div" style="position: absolute; z-index: 99; margin: 0px; padding: 0px; opacity: 0.7; text-align: left; visibility: visible; top: 0px; vertical-align: middle; background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255); left: 396px; height: 58px; width: 75px;"><div style="text-align:right;margin:0;padding:0;background:none;border:none;"><img style="border:none;background:none;margin: 18px 0 0 0px;background:none;border:none;" src="https://back10.keycaptcha.com/js/rightsolution.png" border="0"></div><canvas id="kc_sample_image" style="position: absolute; left: 2px; top: 1px; border: 0px solid rgb(87, 86, 86); z-index: 98;" width="55" height="42"></canvas></div></div><div id="s_s_c_div_adv" style="position: absolute; left: 0px; top: 160px; width: 472px; z-index: 5000; margin: 0px; padding: 0px; opacity: 1; text-align: left; background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255); height: 61px;"><div id="s_s_c_div_adv2" style="overflow:hidden; background-color:#FFFFFF; float:left; height:60px;"><div id="kc_ga_div"><script async="true" src="//pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/js/adsbygoogle.js"></script><ins class="adsbygoogle" style="display:inline-block;width:468px;height:60px" data-ad-client="ca-pub-3315506213109567" data-ad-slot="8022769735" data-adsbygoogle-status="done"><ins id="aswift_1_expand" style="display:inline-table;border:none;height:60px;margin:0;padding:0;position:relative;visibility:visible;width:468px;background-color:transparent"><ins id="aswift_1_anchor" style="display:block;border:none;height:60px;margin:0;padding:0;position:relative;visibility:visible;width:468px;background-color:transparent"><iframe marginwidth="0" marginheight="0" vspace="0" hspace="0" allowtransparency="true" scrolling="no" allowfullscreen="true" onload="var i=this.id,s=window.google_iframe_oncopy,H=s&amp;&amp;s.handlers,h=H&amp;&amp;H[i],w=this.contentWindow,d;try{d=w.document}catch(e){}if(h&amp;&amp;d&amp;&amp;(!d.body||!d.body.firstChild)){if(h.call){setTimeout(h,0)}else if(h.match){try{h=s.upd(h,i)}catch(e){}w.location.replace(h)}}" id="aswift_1" name="aswift_1" style="left:0;position:absolute;top:0;width:468px;height:60px;" height="60" frameborder="0" width="468"></iframe></ins></ins></ins></div></div></div><canvas id="vRmTACEq" style="position: absolute; left: 4px; top: 4px; border: 1px solid rgb(87, 86, 86); z-index: 98;" width="60" height="60"></canvas><canvas id="xvIevNWHk" style="position: absolute; left: 8px; top: 8px; border: 1px solid rgb(87, 86, 86); z-index: 98;" width="60" height="60"></canvas></div><img id="s_s_c_loading" style="position: absolute; background: transparent none repeat scroll 0% 0%; top: 0px; left: 0px; display: none;" src="https://back10.keycaptcha.com/js/loading-keycaptcha.gif"><span id="s_s_c_pleasewait"></span><a id="s_s_c_audiobutton" title="Play audio version of KeyCAPTCHA" style="position:absolute; z-index:1000; border:none; top:4px; right:4px; margin:0; padding:0; visibility:hidden; line-height:normal;" href="javascript:s_s_c_play_audio_captcha();"><img style="margin:0; padding:0; border:none; background:none;" src="https://back10.keycaptcha.com/js/audio.png" border="0"></a><a id="s_s_c_logo" title="Learn more about KeyCAPTCHA" alt="go to www.keycaptcha.com" style="position: absolute; z-index: 1000; border: medium none; bottom: 2px; right: 2px; margin: 0px; padding: 0px; visibility: visible; line-height: normal; display: none;" target="_blank" href="https://www.keycaptcha.com/?refid=112478"><img style="margin:0; padding:0; border:none; background:none;" src="https://back10.keycaptcha.com/js/logo-small-new.png" border="0"></a><div id="s_s_c_wrong_div" style="position: absolute; visibility: hidden; padding: 0px; margin: 0px; top: 0px; width: 474px;"><img id="s_s_c_wrong_img" style="background:none;" src="https://back10.keycaptcha.com/js/wrong-solution.png"></div><div id="s_s_c_checked_div" style="position: absolute; visibility: hidden; padding: 0px; margin: 0px; top: 0px; width: 474px;"><img id="s_s_c_checked_img" style="background:none;" src="https://back10.keycaptcha.com/js/checked.png"></div><div id="s_s_c_please_wait_div" style="position: absolute; visibility: hidden; padding: 0px; margin: 0px; top: 0px; width: 474px;"><img id="s_s_c_please_wait_img" style="background:none;" src="https://back10.keycaptcha.com/js/rlw.gif"></div></div><div id="s_s_c_flogod" style="display:block;"><embed type="application/x-shockwave-flash" allowscriptaccess="always" allowfullscreen="false" menu="false" name="s_s_c_flogo" wmode="transparent" loop="true" play="true" bgcolor="#ffffff" scale="showall" pluginspage="https://www.adobe.com/go/getflashplayer" id="s_s_c_flogo" src="https://back10.keycaptcha.com/js/keycaptcha-logo?r=0.8901021581563917" height="1px" width="1px"></div></div><!-- end of KeyCAPTCHA code -->                                                                                                                                        </div>
                                                                                                                                              </td>
    </tr>
        <tr>
      <td colspan="2" class="SubmitContainer">
        <input name="object[id]" value="1658913" id="object_id" type="hidden"><input name="object[ru][id]" value="1658913" id="object_ru_id" type="hidden"><input name="object[ru][lang]" value="ru" id="object_ru_lang" type="hidden"><input name="object[superfly]" value="77cd45d9b55c4db9af525f5124d59ed2" id="object_superfly" type="hidden">
        <script type="text/javascript">
          $(document).ready(function () {
            $('#object_superfly').val('77cd45d9b55c4db9af525f5124d59ed2');
          });
        </script>        <div class="HR" style="margin: 0 0 15px 0"></div>
        <input id="submit_object_form" value="Сохранить измененния" type="submit">
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody></table>
    <input name="objects_count_before_submit" id="objects_count_before_submit" value="204012534" type="hidden">
        <script>
 var objects_count=204012534;
        document.getElementById("objects_count_before_submit").value=objects_count;
    </script>
</form>
```

Comment: Проблема в том, что у форм есть поля, а у полей есть имена. Так вот, чтобы автоматом заполнить поле надо знать либо его имя, либо идентификатор, указывающий, что это поле относится для заполнения только количества комнат например или только для заполнения описания. Т.к. сайты разные,то и идентификаторов общих у них нет. универсального скрипта написать нельзя. Более того, у некоторых и форм может не быть, просто берут через js данные из полей и отправляют через ajax. Еще хлеще - полей форм может и не быть, а просто div contenteditable. Итог:единого скрипта на все формы всех сайтов быть не может

Comment: @АлексейШиманский сейчас вставлю код сайта там где формы в шапку.

Comment: @АлексейШиманский мне бы понять, как сделать, что бы хоть 1 поле заполнилось автоматически при использовании скрипта, дальше я сам попробую разобраться.

Comment: Ты кажется не всё прочитал, что я написал или не уловил суть...... на одном сайте Площадь (м кв.) имеет идентификатор `object_form_row_square_total`, а на другом `sqr_area`, на третьем еще какой-либо. соответственно тебе придется для каждого сайта менять идентификаторы в коде. каждый раз для каждого нового сайта.  в итоге автоматизации не получится. не может её быть в данном случае

Comment: @АлексейШиманский хорошо, а для этого сайта как мне вынести значение в инпут на самом сайте при помощи js?

Comment: Читай ответ  в дубликате)

Comment: @АлексейШиманский я прочел, но как бы смешно это не звучало, я все равно не понял)

Comment: допустим у тебя есть  инпут с типом **text** `<input name="object[square_land]" class="InputMedium" id="object_square_land" type="text">` и его идентификатор `object_square_land`.....значит добавить в него текст можно так : `document.getElementById('object_square_land').value = "Мой произвольный текст";`

Comment: @АлексейШиманский ещё один глупый вопрос. Это значение которое я буду вводить в "мой произвольный текст", как мне его отправить в поле вода на доске?

Comment: @АлексейШиманский Я уже разобрался, спасибо большое.